# Netbios in AD console

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, netbios

I was wondering, in the AD users $ computers console, it's using the netbios name to display the machine name. Is there a way to use the DNS name instead of the netbios?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you referring to? If you are talking about just the Objects themselves, in an OU, then they are actually the unqualified DNS names.  They just aren't the FQDN, which you can see in the `DNS name:` attribute in the object properties.  Likewise, you can see the Netbios name in the `Computer name (pre-Windows 2000):` attribute.

What is that you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: basically im trying to find a correct way to name my machines in all my location. So i wanted to put LOC-FIRSTLXX where LOC is location, FIRST is the user first name, L is the user first initial of last name and XX is a number. Because we already had the case where users have very long names i am afraid the in AD it will not show up correctly.

Comment: Why not name them LOC-PCXXXX where the X's start at 0001.  Then keep the description updated with the current user.  Otherwise you may run into a case where a user leaves or switches PCs and then your naming scheme is off.

Comment: @Alex Naming a PC after a user that uses it isn't very scalable. You'll have to rename the PC every time someone gets married, leaves, is hired, etc. Use a description field for this if you must.

Comment: everytime a new employe starts he gets a freshly imaged laptop, and every user has its own laptop. I wanted to put the user's name so it's easier for helpdesk and you dont have to go through a lot of things to know which machine the user's on.

Comment: Alex: There's no "way" that's defined by some shadowy cabal of IT gods on Mount Olympus as the correct way. There's my way, and your way, and his way and her way, etc. Implement a naming convention that suits your needs and objectives and that will be the correct way.

Comment: @Alex When you name a computer, use a label maker to print out the name and put it in a visible spot. Then when the user  calls the helpdesk, they can read that label over the phone. Doing it like this will save the helpdesk a headache while saving you the headache of renaming every time a name changes.

Answer (score 1):

It's not using the NetBIOS name. It's using the `name` attribute in Active Directory, which it gets from the computer name when the machine is joined from AD. You can customize the ADUC snap-in to show whatever attributes you want. There's not really any reason to view the FQDN over the Display Name, though, so I don't know what you're going for.